# how can I check which version of vim I have installed?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, vim, version

I'm running Mac OS X Snow Leopard. How can I check which version of vim I have installed?

Ideally I'd like to know a general solution for checking software versions via the command line.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The command:

```
vim --version
```

This is pretty standard for all unix executables.

Comment: It should be mentioned that this command should be entered in the terminal, not inside vim. And you should have vim added to your environment variables if you are on a Windows.

Comment: It is worth noting that if all that is wanted is a version number and nothing else (for example, for purposes of deciding whether to take some action based on the version number), then the `--version` output needs to be parsed. I am not aware of a direct way to get Vim's version number (and only the version number) from the command line. Nor am I aware whether line 1 of the output is guaranteed to match a parsing specification. As for a parsing example, in Linux environments you could do: `vim --version | head -1 | sed -e 's|^[^0-9]*||' -e 's| .*||'`

Comment: An alternative, more memorable way to filter out the version from the very verbose --version output is `vim --version | head -n1`

Answer (score 29):

or, just if you run vim already and want to know what you are in right now:

```
:version
```

Answer (score 3):

In a terminal run `vim --version` ther version number is in the top line of output.

Answer (score 2):

You can also just open a blank VIM document by typing vi or vim in your terminal. The welcome screen will state your version as well as other information.

Answer (score 0):

For `vim` or `neovim` using regex:

```bsh
vi --version | grep -oP '(?<=^VIM v)[0-9|.]+'
vi --version | grep -oP '(?<=^NVIM v)[0-9|.]+'
```

Assumes your `grep` has perl compatible regex (PCRE).